# How to start application on paired android device from Google Glass?

Tags: bluetooth, google-glass, google-gdk

Is there a way to send an intent from google glass and start application on paired android device ?

Comment: You can send intents over adb to launch applications. On android there are remote adb clients that could possibly work with your glass. 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cgutman.androidremotedebugger

Comment: I would like to fire intent from running Google Glass application.

Comment: Possibly theres a way to use Launchy, if you connect to a remote device and populate it with the launch activities on your phone. https://github.com/kaze0/launchy/tree/master/src/com/mikedg/android/glass/launchy